# How to track coordinates on mapkit

Tags: ios, xcode, screen, mapkit, coordinates

Is it possible to locate mapkit coordinates of the user screen center? I need to remember maps last coordinates of user's screen and put them on application launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[yourMapView centerCoordinate]
```

or

```
[[yourMapView region] center]
```

(Typed directly in browser, try it)

Comment: how do I get from this numbers?

Comment: This will return you a CLLocationCoordinate2D object, from which you can get a latitude and a longitude. You do whatever you want with them. If you need to recenter the mapview to this point, just assign it to the mapview's centerCoordinate property.